# The type or namespace name 'PROJECTNAME' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day Everyone. I'm currently doing a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application in which I have created two Views namely *MainPageMain.xaml* and *SecondPage.xaml*. In App.cs, I have set my root page to **MainPageMain** but I want to change it to **SecondPage**.

Everytime I changed it, this error appears:

***The type or namespace name 'PROJECTNAME' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?***

[image]

What's the reason behind this? If you need more codes, just let me know.

This is my code for SecondPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.SecondPage"
         BackgroundColor="Teal">

  <Label Text="Sample Here!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

This is my code for SecondPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Views;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
    {
        public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
        {
        public SecondPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

App.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SecondPage());


        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecondPage` class may be in a namespace, that you need to add by the using statement. This may be the reason for the problem. To check it further, You can post some more code.

Comment: You should check where the `SecondPage` class resides in your code. I guess you will get your answer. Also, check the `xaml` form for the class `SecondPage`.

Comment: one more thing that you can do is to search the term `PROJECTNAME` in your project to resolve the issue, as this is included in your exception details.

Comment: no Sir. I just put the term "PROJECTNAME" to denote the name of the view.

Comment: In your App.cs file include `using XamarinFormsDemo.Views` namespace at the top. or you can use fully qualified name as `XamarinFormsDemo.Views.SecondPage()` in place of `SecondPage`. Hope it Helps.

Comment: I did that Sir but another error appeared stating 
"The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context". What should I do now?

Comment: Your question is now answered. The error you are getting says that the function does not exist. You need to create it. check `MainPageMain` class that will have the same function. You can get help from that class. Also If your main problem is solved, Please accept it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: My question has not yet been answered correctly because it displayed another error. Therefore it's not yet done. Can you show me the exact code by editing my Post please?

Comment: However, I'll accept that as an aswer. Thanks Man :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add InitializeComponent() in your secondpage.xaml.cs

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(MainPage));
        }
```

it's work for me.